# Patching lksctp RPM in linux

Tags: kernel, patch, rpm, rpmbuild, sctp

I am using a homegrown customized Linux that is a derivative of Oracle Linux 6 but I need to pickup all the patches from the lksctp-tools-1.0.17-2.el7.src.rpm and patch in my lksctp-tools-1.0.11-1 rpm package.

I found there are two new patches in 1.0.17-2.el7 version:

```
lksctp-tools-1.0.17-sctp_status-fix-hostname-resolution.patch
lksctp-tools-1.0.6-libdir.patch
```

I copied the above patches in the patches directory where I built a build environment and during building the new RPM I face hunk failed for the last patch:

```
Patch #5 (lksctp-tools-1.0.17-sctp_status-fix-hostname-resolution.patch):
+ /bin/cat /workdirs/BuildUser/build/RPM/SOURCES/lksctp-tools-1.0.17-sctp_status-fix-hostname-resolution.patch
+ /usr/bin/patch -p1 --fuzz=0
patching file src/apps/sctp_status.c
+ echo 'Patch #6 (lksctp-tools-1.0.6-libdir.patch):'
Patch #6 (lksctp-tools-1.0.6-libdir.patch):
+ /bin/cat /workdirs/BuildUser/build/RPM/SOURCES/lksctp-tools-1.0.6-libdir.patch
+ /usr/bin/patch -p1 --fuzz=0
patching file src/withsctp/withsctp.in
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file src/withsctp/withsctp.in.rej
error: Bad exit status from /workdirs/BuildUser/tmp/rpm-tmp.nJHnek (%prep)
```

I have mentioned the patches in my specfile:

```
Name: lksctp-tools
Version: %{pack_version}
Release: ~RELEASE~
License: LGPL
Group: System Environment/Libraries
URL: http://lksctp.sourceforge.net
Source0: %{name}-%{file_version}.tar.gz
Patch0: lksctp-tools-linux-3.4.38-sctp.patch
Patch1: lksctp-tools-sctp-per-association-stats.patch
Patch2: lksctp-tools-fix-deprecated-SO_RCVBUF-SO_SNDBUF-testcase.patch
Patch3: lksctp-tools-Avoid-using-file-descriptor-0-to-get-ENOTSOCK.patch
Patch4: lksctp-tools-test_fragments-increase-message-size-since-it-succeeds.patch
Patch5: lksctp-tools-1.0.17-sctp_status-fix-hostname-resolution.patch
Patch6: lksctp-tools-1.0.6-libdir.patch
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-buildroot
BuildRequires: gcc
BuildRequires: libtool, automake, autoconf
%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}-%{file_version}
%patch0 -p1
%patch1 -p1
%patch2 -p1
%patch3 -p1
%patch4 -p1
%patch5 -p1
%patch6 -p1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The patch failed because the source doesn't match. Before automating with `rpm`, make sure you can apply the patches yourself manually, *in the order given in the specfile*. Another possible issue - did the newer source RPM replace an older patch with one of these new ones?